# C# Regex get elements inside expression

Tags: c#

I am trying to get elements from an expression contained inside a string.

E.g.: Get elements from expression where expression1 is

`@@Expr[propAge>10?'ignore>':'ignore?']`

and expression2 is

`@@Expr[PropSex='M'?'ignore>']"`

In this case, I'm interested in getting two string arrays from the above string

```
array1 = ["propAge",">","'ignore>'","'ignore?'"]
array2 = ["propSex","=","'M'","'ignore>'"]
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think the question was totally destroyed by edits. I think the text after *"E.g.: "* was originally meant to be the source string to be analyzed in order to get the result?!

Comment: You should **first try** something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
\[(.+?)([<>=])(.+?)\?(.+?)(?::(.+?))?]
```

should work.

Note that this will likely fail if there are backslash escapes or colons within the two last operators.

[image: Regexr test.]

Comment: Thank you . This gives me the first occurrence. How can I get all occurrence of  Regex in my string ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually writing a parser with just regex is a bad idea, as you run into all kinds of fun problems when trying to distinguish similar tokens in different contexts. Also, only two samples are often insufficient to write a good regex from.

That being said, in your case you can probably use something like the following:

```
(?xi) # turn on comments mode and case-insensitivity
  '[^']+'   # strings like 'ignore?'
|
  (?<=\[.*) # ensure that there's an opening square bracket to the left
            # to not match the @@Expr part
  [a-z]+    # matches e.g. propAge
|
  [<>=]     # operators
```

This uses a large alternation to match the different parts of the expression.